# Forever loop in Django?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

Is it possible to have an infinite loop in Django which listens to a queue? For example:

```
class tester():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self):
        while (True):
            print("Does this block?2")

    def tester(self):
        while(True):
            print("Does this block?")

class Test(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        test = tester()

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=test.test)
        t1.start()

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=test.tester)
        t2.start()
```

It seems to block at the first loop. Any pointers on how to start two forever loops on Django?

Edit: I noticed that when I add a very small sleep time, the second thread can start. Anybody know why this is the case? For example:

```
class tester():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self):
        while (True):
            time.sleep(0.0001)
            print("Does this block?2")

    def tester(self):
        while(True):
            print("Does this block?")

class Test(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        test = tester()

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=test.test)
        t1.start()

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=test.tester)
        t2.start()
```

Comment: What is it printing out exactly? Also, what are you trying to achieve? This may be an XY problem.

Comment: Hello - Well I actually just want one forever loop to run in the background. It's supposed to continuously check if a queue is not empty and run a function is so.

Comment: I would probably use one of the Django packages meant for this, see this link: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/

Comment: What is it printing out exactly?

Comment: I've tried creating tasks but it just causes latency. I'm trying to avoid any latency. Right now, it's printing "Does this block?2" continuously and doesn't ever print "Does this block?". If I put this outside of my Django App (in a separate python script), "Does this block?2" and "Does this block?" both print.

Comment: Edited original comment.

Comment: Just to let you know, "blocking" has a specific meaning in programming, it is the opposite of "asynchronous". When you talk about "blocking", I thought you meant that "Does this block?" gets printed once and nothing else happens, as it "blocks" on that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are handled by the operating system. In your case, it looks like the operating system is allowing the first thread to run, and never giving the second thread an opportunity to run.

The operating system does not provide any guarantees about the priority of the scheduling of the threads. Let's say you have two threads, with two instructions each:

```
thread 1:
- instruction 1.1
- instruction 1.2

thread 2:
- instruction 2.1
- instruction 2.2
```

If you launch both threads almost simultaneously, the operating system can choose to run it in this order:

```
instruction 1.1
instruction 1.2
instruction 2.1
instruction 2.1
```

or in this order:

```
instruction 2.1
instruction 2.2
instruction 1.1
instruction 1.1
```

or in this order:

```
instruction 2.1
instruction 1.1
instruction 2.2
instruction 1.2
```

or in any other order, as long as the instructions in each thread stay in order relative to the other instructions within that thread.

So the operating system doesn't provide any guarantees that it will interleave the `print` statements from thread 1 with the print statements from thread 2. It can choose to prioritise thread 1 over thread 2 if it wants. If it sees a `sleep` statement, it may choose to take that into consideration when scheduling the threads.

Also, bear in mind that Python uses a GIL for multiple threads. Python may have decided to keep thread 1 running to avoid the overhead of releasing and locking the GIL, or something like that.

There are tools to combat this problem. You could use a thread pool of short-lived tasks, or use locks, or semaphores, or other tools. I'm not a specialist in these tools, so hopefully someone will provide a better answer than mine.